# TeamCity - Copy files from commit that triggered build

Tags: file, svn, teamcity, copying

I am using the "VCS Trigger" trigger: "Triggers one build per each VCS check-in".

I have two Build steps:

1. One that runs the .sln file
2. Another that copies files to the destination webroot.

Is there a way to configure TeamCity so that it only copies to the destination webroot the files that were part of the commit that triggered the build process?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend that, since .net solutions are bundled together so that files from one build may not work in another build. At least that is my experience...